# For any constant $c>0$, $\sum\limits_{p\le n, \;p \;is\;prime} \frac{1}{\ln p}<c\frac{n}{\ln n}$ holds $\forall$ sufficiently large $n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is the following result correct?

> For any constant $c>0$,
> $$\sum\limits_{p\le n, \;p \;is\;prime} \frac{1}{\ln p}<c\frac{n}{\ln n}$$
> holds $\forall$ sufficiently large $n$

If yes, can someone please help me with proof?

Comment: You can try to use the PNT $\pi(n) \sim n/\log(n)$ and the inequalities $\log(2) \leq \log(p) \leq \log(n)$ for primes $p \leq n$ to get started.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not hard. Just need to notice:
$\sum\limits_{p\le n}\frac{\ln n}{\ln p}=\sum\limits_{p\le n}\log_pn\le\sum\limits_{p^k|n}1+\pi(n)\le2\pi(n)+n^\frac{1}{2}+n^\frac{1}{3}+...+n^\frac{1}{\log_2n+1}<2\pi(n)+\sqrt n\log_2n=o(n)$

which finishes the proof.